# Mask a Y array to only get its values for X1==X2

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two sets of points whose coordinates are stored in the arrays X1 Y1 and X2 Y2 respectively. We do **not** have the same number of points in the sets 1 and 2.

What I'm trying to do is mask the longest Y array (it will always be known) to get the Y value of the points that are available in both sets. For context, this is because I want to calculate a correlation factor between raw experimental data and sliding-averaged data. The sliding average crops a few points (as many as the selected averaging window width) so the raw data array is always larger.

I tried this but it only works when X1 and X2 have the same size:

```
# Base data
X1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
Y1 = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
X2 = np.array([2,3,4])
Y2 = np.array([200,300,400])

# Y data that share an X
Y1_with_common_X = Y1[X1 == X2] # expected result: y2 == np.array([20,30,40])

# analyze the cropped data (this function is already written and works fine)
R2 = correlation(Y2, Y1_with_common_X)
```

How to do for different sized arrays? Thanks in advance.

Edit: here is a picture, it's clearer.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need [np.isin()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
Y1[np.isin(X1, X2)]
#[20 30 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make shortened views of the arrays:

```
length = min(len(X1), len(X2))
X1s = X1[:length]
Y1s = Y1[:length]
X2s = X2[:length]
Y2s = Y2[:length]
```

Comment: No because this will always crop the end of the arrays, while my extra points are located on both sides, not just right.

Comment: Oh I see.  Well, should have written a more relevant example then!  I'm sure you can take it from here though.